# 'In a hurry', why is this used with the infinite article 'a'?

Tags: idioms, indefinite-article

I was so confused with this.  So I look up the word 'hurry' in the Oxford dictionary and I found that it is an uncountable noun. Is it possible to use 'a' before 'hurry'?

Why is it possible? Do I need to think this as an idiomatic phrase? I don't just want to memorise this. I want to know the reason why there is 'a'.

Comment: It's an idiomatic expression, so your only option is memorization.  This expression probably covers 90% of the cases where you will use "hurry" as a noun, though

Answer (score 0):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hurry) and [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hurry) define it as singular.

I can see why [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hurry) considers it to be a mass noun, because it is not in the plural in negative sentences.

> I have no apples - *countable, plural*
>   I have no sugar - *uncountable, not plural*
>   I am in no hurry - *not plural*

But simply saying it's always singular explains this, and also explains why it can take **a**.

Comment: So does Collins: [hurry](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hurry) #3.

Comment: Thanks, @user3169. I have added that to my answer.

Comment: There are other ways in which "hurry" is used as a mass noun, besides the negative "no hurry". If, for example, you say *His attitude was one of hurry and urgency*, or *Hurry was at the heart of everything she did*.